# Multiple asynchronous UI updates in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, callback

How does one execute several UI updates from a Silverlight callback?

For example, I would like the user to click a button, have the UI make a change, do some work, then make another change...  instead, the user clicks the button and the callback seems to execute in the background and then all of the UI changes flash before my eyes.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" >
<TextBlock Height="23" Name="textBlock1" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Button Click="button1_Click" Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="75"  />
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBlock1.Text = "1";
    // also tried Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => Thread.Sleep(5000));
    textBlock1.Text = "2";
}
```

Comment: Instead of sleeping the thread during the time the work is being done, you can have an event get fired after the work is done. The listener of that event will then make the 2nd UI change.

Comment: @iimpact The Sleep call is just filling in for the work.  The question is, why doesn't the first UI update take place before the Sleep call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight uses a queue of work items to handle rendering and logic on the UI thread.  Since your logic also runs on the UI thread (in your `button_Click` handler) the renderer doesn't get a chance to draw the screen until your method is done executing AND the internal message loop gets around to drawing the screen.

Your `BeginInvoke` immediately places your function on the Silverlight work queue to execute on the UI thread (and returns immediately).  The order Silverlight processes this is probably something like:

- User clicks the button, placing a click event on the work queue
- Silverlight sees the click event and calls `button_Click` (which places a new action on the work queue)
- Process the next work queue item which is probably your `Thread.Sleep` action, pausing the UI thread for 5 seconds
- Finally Silverlight gets around to painting the screen

What you want to do is start a new thread to do your work, then `BeginInvoke` *back* to the UI thread:

```
var thread = new Thread(() => {
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { 
    // update UI 
    textBox.Text = "2";
  });
});

textBox.Text = "1";
thread.Start();
```

I should add that Silverlight 5 adds a composition thread that can perform certain actions to update the UI without blocking the UI thread like playing animations and doing GPU accelerated rendering where possible.

Comment: Thanks.  Why can't I force the update with something like:  { tb1.Text="1"; UpdateLayout(); Thread.Sleep(1000); tb2.Text="2"; } ?

Comment: `UpdateLayout` only performs the [measure and arrange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645025%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) steps of the layout process.  The drawing still is scheduled through the work queue just like everything else.  As far as I know there is no immediate mode screen rendering in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

The [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx) runs asynchronously and therefore will return and change the text.

Directly from MSDN Documentation: "BeginInvoke is asynchronous; therefore, control returns immediately to the calling object after it is called."

Instead in the BeginInvoke add the processing that you want to do. So you do Thread.Sleep and then add the change the textbox.

[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) also can tie into events. So when the UI is updated aka BackGroundWorker completed event you can kick of the next item. Here is why you should use the [BgroundWorker](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/228193/553921.aspx/1?Re%20BackgorundWorker%20vs%20Thread%20classes)

i.e.

```
BackgroundWorker w = new BackgroundWorker();
w.DoWork += (sender, args) => 
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
    //your code here
    }); 
};
w.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: It looks like the Silverlight Dispatcher does not contain an Invoke method, so that the Dispatcher can only be used asynchronously.   Even so, I still don't see why the first change is not visible immediately, in any case.

Comment: @jordanpg yes sorry, however, I edited it to an even better answer if the Invoke still existed.

Comment: that looks like what I've already got...  Even more mysteriously, if I try: private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ textBlock1.Text = "1"; Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); textBlock1.Text = "2"; }); textBlock1.Text = "3"; } the last UI update doesn't even occur!

Comment: This is because text is changed to 1. BeginInvoke is called and returns. It sets text to 3. Approximately 5 seconds later Text becomes 2. The screen does not update faster enough so you cannot see. One solution is to use events or Change BeginInvokes. I think you don't fully understand this asynch style programming.

Comment: the point is, *the text does not change to 1* even with the BeginInvoke call removed.  So even if I do: { tb1.Text="1"; Thread.Sleep(1000); tb1.text="3"; }, I still only see a 3.

Comment: The UI Threads will queue the events. Therefore if events happen quick enough it will aggregate and prevent common events. Also when you do a Thread.Sleep on the UI Thread, it cannot update. Instead run the code on the BackgroundWorker (See Edit)

Comment: This solution worked for my problem! `new Thread()` and `Thread.Start()` were still blocking the UI thread, not sure why. However, `BackgroundWorker` unblocks immediately.